# Get values from google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I am very new to App Script but was generally wondering if what I want to do is possible... any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

So, I have a google spreadsheet with some columns set up like this:

```
Column A   Column B

name       name.com
name2      name2.com
name3      name3.com
```

I would like to be able to get ALL of the values in each column and parse them into a format similar to this for the eventual file that I can copy and paste somewhere else:

```
<#function linker trackerName>
<#local link = { 
"name" : "name.com", 
"name2" : "name2.com",
"name" : "name2.com"

}>
</#function>
```

I'm guessing that's very possible with app script, but I'm just not sure the format or how to make that parse to a text file?

Again any help or guidance for a launching point would be awesome!

here's the script I'm tinkering with.. I've made a menu but when I run the function, nothing happens:

```
 function onOpen() {
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   ui.createMenu('Get Values')
       .addItem('Go!', 'getValues')
       .addToUi();
    }


   function getValues() {

   var values = 
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

    values.forEach( function(row) {
    row[0] // column index as 4 ... I beleive this should get all values 
    in each row / column? 
    });
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your current script? It will help users think of your solutions.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've updated my original question with the code.. it doesn't seem to do anything when I run it though

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do with the function you've written. Are you creating an object to give to other functions? Are you trying to write new data to the sheet? etc.

Comment: what I would like to do ideally, is to grab all the values in each column of a google sheet so that I can have them automatically inserted into another document.  I would then just have that document as a template with the code inserted from the google sheets every time.

Comment: added more comments to make it more clear... sorry, I'm just learning this and it's more daunting than I thought

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can I ask you about your question? What is ``automatically``? You want to manually run the script? Or you want to use some triggers for running the script? And I cannot understand about what you want to do. So can you provide the input and output you want? (for example, by using sample spreadsheet) By this, it will help users understand you want.

Comment: sure thing, sorry my term wasn't clear... what I am hoping to do is to be on the spreadsheet... run the script from the menu... then it would create a new google doc from a template with the values from column A and B inserted into the document in 2 different spots.

Comment: Here's a spreadsheet example: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u1sRNmXSzmuMGLOQehJl4b6cBIJu6yl3VlKFcLmWSC8/edit?usp=sharing

Here's a google doc example for the template: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1m9f-VhofkdO1lt5PDV-dm1tRu4dQFynVPPkEy-fRDf4/edit

Comment: @Mixmastermiike Thank you for replying. 1. You want to manually run the script from menu bar. 2. You want to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet. 3. You want to create new Document including the text values which added the retrieved values. If my understanding is correct, I think that the template is not required to be in the Document. You can use the template in the script. How about this? And if my understanding is not correct, please tell me.

Comment: @tanaike thanks for replying - yes your understanding is correct, the template can be used in the script if it's better to do it that way.

Comment: @Mixmastermiike Thank you for replying. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You want to manually run the script from menu bar.
2. You want to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet.
3. You want to create new Document including the text values which added the retrieved values.
4. Template can be used at the script.

I understand about what you want like above. When this is reflected to your script, how about this modification? The flow of this script is as follows. I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Flow:

1. Set template values to `tempHeader` and `tempFooter`.
2. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
3. Convert the retrieved values for using at the template.
4. Merge the converted values and template values.
5. Create new Document and set the values.

#### Modified script:

```
function getValues() {
  var fileName = "sampleName"; // This is a filename of new Document.

  var tempHeader = "<#function linker trackerName>\n<#local link = {\n";
  var tempFooter = "\n}>\n</#function>\n";
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var v = values.slice(1, values.length);
  var res = v.map(function(e, i){return '"' + e[0] + '" : "' + e[1] + '"' + (i < v.length - 1 ? "," : "")}).join("\n");
  DocumentApp.create(fileName).getBody().setText(tempHeader + res + tempFooter);
}
```

#### Note:

- `onOpen()` in your script can be used. When the spreadsheet is opened, you can run the script at the menu bar.
- In this modified script, the filename of new Document is `fileName`. So please modify this to your situation.
- I was worry about the possibility that there are the same values in column "A". So when the values are converted, I didn't process as the object.

Comment: WOW! It works... I was kind of confused what you meant but yes, it creates a new google doc every time we run the google sheets script.  I need to modify it a little bit but this is exactly what I need.  Thanks so so much for the help today! This will really make things more efficient on a project I'm working on.

Comment: @Mixmastermiike I'm really sorry for the inconvenience and my incomplete answer. From your question and comments, I couldn't understand what you want to do after the new Document was created. What can I do for your situation?

Comment: oh no worries at all, thanks so much for answering this works probably better than what I had in mind originally anyway :)

Comment: @Mixmastermiike Thank you for your concern. If you have any questions for this, feel free to tell me. I would like to think of the solution.